# Самописная функция sort

Tags: c++, сортировка

Мне нужно отсортировать массив не используя функцию sort. Как будет выглядеть самописный аналог этой функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что значит аналог?
алгоритмов сортировки море с разной средней, минимальной и максимальной производительностью

самое примитивное - O(n^2) сложность - цикл в цикле - сначала проходите по циклу и находите минимальное значение меняете его местами с 1 значением, потом проходите по циклу уже со второго значения до последнего, ищите минимального и заменяете его местами со 2 значением и т.д.

всего вам понадобится `n * n / 2` этапов цикла

но это мягко говоря не самый оптимальный алгоритм сортировки :)

Comment: "самое примитивное - O(n^2)" - это далеко не худший вариант - [Bogosort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) :D

Comment: не худший, но как мне кажется один из самых примитивных

Answer (score 0):

[merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) особенно легко написать на C++ с использованием функции `std::merge`. Вся реализация укладывается в 10 строк. Работает за оптимальное время `NlogN`.

[quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) также реализуется очень легко благодаря `std::partition`. Реализация займёт строк семь. Среднее время `NlogN`, худшее `N^2`.

Если совсем нельзя использовать высокоуровневые процедуры, то [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) займёт пять строк (`std::swap` подразумевается). Время `N^2`.